# Python: if counted number of files does not equal x then retry report pull

Tags: python, selenium

I am attempting to count the number of files in the directory I am saving my reports to.  If the number of files do not equal X+1 then I would like to re-run the middle part of the code that downloads the report.  I have to use this method because I am dealing with CSV files and they download in sequential order (Report(1), Report(2), ect.).  I am then changing the names of these reports to there real names later in the code.

```
import time
import os
import os.path
import glob
import shutil
from selenium.webdriver.common.action_chains import ActionChains
from selenium.common.exceptions import MoveTargetOutOfBoundsException
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.common.keys import Keys
from selenium.common.exceptions import NoSuchElementException
from selenium.common.exceptions import NoAlertPresentException

files = glob.glob('/Users/me/Desktop/AUTOREPORTS/*')
for f in files:
    os.remove(f)        

open('/Users/me/Desktop/AUTOREPORTS/report.csv', "w")

for x in range(1, 73):      
    while True:    
        try:
            fp = webdriver.FirefoxProfile('C:/Users/me/Documents/FirefoxProfile')
            browser = webdriver.Firefox(fp)
            browser.get('https://website.com/')

            time.sleep(8)

            browser.find_element_by_id("ctl00_PlaceHolderMain_login_UserName").clear()
            browser.find_element_by_id("ctl00_PlaceHolderMain_login_UserName").send_keys("USER")
            browser.find_element_by_id("ctl00_PlaceHolderMain_login_password").clear()
            browser.find_element_by_id("ctl00_PlaceHolderMain_login_password").send_keys("PWD")
            browser.find_element_by_id("ctl00_PlaceHolderMain_login_login").click()

#gets user to reporting front end

            ReportMgr= browser.find_element_by_partial_link_text('Report Manager')
            ReportMgr.click()

            time.sleep(5)

            CustomReport= browser.find_element_by_partial_link_text('Custom Report')
            CustomReport.click()

            time.sleep(5)

            ProgramManagement= browser.find_element_by_partial_link_text('Program Management')
            ProgramManagement.click()
            ProgramManagement= browser.find_element_by_partial_link_text('Program Management').send_keys(Keys.ARROW_LEFT)

#pulls reports

            browser.find_element_by_partial_link_text('Program Management').click()
            time.sleep(60)
            browser.find_element_by_partial_link_text('Program Management').send_keys(Keys.ARROW_DOWN * x, Keys.ENTER)
            time.sleep(60)
            try:
                browser.find_element_by_css_selector("#ctl00_PlaceHolderMain_ReportViewer1_HtmlOutputReportResults2_updateFilters_TitleAnchor").click()            
            except NoSuchElementException:
                pass           
            time.sleep(140)            
            browser.find_element_by_css_selector("#ctl00_PlaceHolderMain_ReportViewer1_HtmlOutputReportResults2_CSVButton_ImageAnchor > img").click()
            time.sleep(140)            
            fname = "Report(%s).csv" % (x)
            os.chdir('/Users/me/Desktop/AUTOREPORTS')
            browser.quit()
            #counts number of files in DIR
            path = 'C:/Users/me/Desktop/AUTOREPORTS'
            count = len([f for f in os.listdir(path) if os.path.isfile(os.path.join(path, f))])
            print count   
            #end count of number of files in DIR
        except:
               browser.quit()           
               continue
        else:
               break
```

This is the part of the code where I get the count - however I am not sure to tell Python that if this count does not equal X+1 then to retry (x):

```
#counts number of files in DIR
                path = 'C:/Users/me/Desktop/AUTOREPORTS'
                count = len([f for f in os.listdir(path) if os.path.isfile(os.path.join(path, f))])
                print count   
                #end count of number of files in DIR
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just a regular `if` statement should do the trick.  Maybe extract that middle part to a function you can call.  That way you don't have to rewrite all that code inside the `if` statement.

```
if count != x + 1:
    # Do what you need to download the file again
```

Also, instead of doing this in a big `try/accept`, use `contextlib` to create a function you can use with the `with` statement. example:

```
from contextlib import contextmanager


@contextmanager
def quitting(thing):
    yield thing
    thing.close()
    thing.quit()
```

Then open your driver like so:

```
with quitting(webdriver.Firefox(fp)) as browser:
    # Put your code here.
```

That way if there are errors, it will call `close` and `quit` on your `WebDriver` instance.

Comment: That's the problem. I don't really know what to do :(  I think it might be             if count == x + 1:     # equal
                print count
            elif count != count + 1:   # not equal
                x - 1
                continue

Comment: @Yogwhatup, Extract the middle part you need to re-run into a function.  Then call the function if you need to re-download the report.

Comment: This got me to where I needed to be - greatly appreciated!